# https://usercontent.googleapis.com/freebase/v1/imageID return "Domain Type Forbidden"

Tags: image, freebase

https://usercontent.googleapis.com/freebase/v1/image/en/jenni_rivera
https://usercontent.googleapis.com/freebase/v1/image/en/bob_dylan

return

```
{
"error": {
    "errors": [
        {
            "domain": "global",
            "reason": "domainTypeForbidden",
            "message": "Domain Type Forbidden"
        }
    ],
    "code": 403,
    "message": "Domain Type Forbidden"
}
}
```

Do i do somthing wrong? API was changed?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, we're looking into it. Right now the images are available from:

```
https://www.googleapis.com/freebase/v1/image/en/jenni_rivera
```

...but it should be switched back to usercontent.googleapis.com very soon.